# Make Alexa Skill Loop a Speech Function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

My Alexa skill queries a MySQL database and verbalizes a random value. Ideally, I want this function to loop. That is, I want Alexa to continue reading random values indefinitely until the user says stop. Is this possible.

Here is my code:

```
   'RandomVerse': function () {

connection.query('SELECT versetext, book, reference  FROM myverses ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1', 
function (error, results, fields) {
     console.log(error)
   console.log(results[0].versetext);
   var scripture = results[0].versetext;
  var book = results[0].book;
   var reference = results[0].reference.replace(":", " verse ");
   this.emit(':tell',scripture + " " + "<say-as interpret-as='ordinal'>" + book + "</say-as>" + " " + reference);

 }.bind(this));

    },
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but... why are you doing this: `JSON.stringify(...).replace(/['"]+/g, '')`?

Comment: @Jordan Running Because `results` by itself returns a JSON string, which Alexa can't verbalize. I'm using stringify to eliminate everything except the desired value. Finally, `replace...` gets red of the unnecessary quotes on each side of my result.

Comment: If `results` was a string, then `results[0]` would return the first character of the string. It looks more like `results` is an array of objects. Regardless, "using stringify to eliminate everything except the desired value" doesn't make any sense. `JSON.stringify` doesn't eliminate anything. It serializes a JavaScript object or value as a JSON string.

Comment: See cleaned up code above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure for the answer but AFAIK you can't do exactly that with alexa, it is either going to be waiting for a response or talking. 
Something that could help you are [notifications](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/notifications-overview.html), which it says can give a visual an audio feedback to the user, so you cold have a second *lambda* doing whatever process and sending notifications to alexa.
Maybe also having an utterence to tell the process to stop.
I haven't tested any of that but it would be my first approach.